# pacer_lib syntax and term "search_agent()"

Tags: python, import, syntax-error

I am trying to use published code and getting a syntax error.   The code is pacer-scraper to print dockets from a government website. I have downloaded the library. I tried to change the path and moved the library to the various directories.

The problem is with the first line.

from pacer_lib.scraper import search_agent()

I am getting a traceback that points to the "()"  --  ideas?

Comment: You can't invoke the function while importing it. Rightly pointed by @wmorrell

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the (). This leads to a traceback that the module is not found.

Comment: Did you correctly install pacer_lib? Also pointing out it's strange but the correct usage include `from pacer_lib.scraper import search_agent()` http://pacer-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/

Comment: Thank you! I did a pip installation of the pacer_lib into the proper directory, and now the code works.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `()`. In Python you import the name, which will be `search_agent`. Adding the parenthesis means you want to call the name, which is not allowed in `import` statements.

Comment: I wondered about the format of the line. The "from. . . import" is something that I have not seen before.  When I remove the parenthesis, the module of the library is not recognized. That made me wonder about the path. "No module named pacer_lib"     Thank you for your prompt reply. I will keep trying.

Comment: It is weird but this doesn't answer the question. Go through this http://pacer-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/

Comment: I was a bit premature in my report that the code worked. I was just happy to get a different traceback.  By adding back the parentheses, I get a syntax error that prevents python from reading any code past the first line.  By removing the parentheses, I get a traceback that refers to two lines- one in my text editor and one in the pacer_lib scraper .  The first reference gives the line number and states "in <module>" and returns the line. The second makes reference to a missing parentheses in a call to print. The code in the library may be better with Python 2.7 (uninstalled).

Comment: Got it.  It turns out that there are tracebacks that require edits to the original .py documents. cStringIO has to be changed, because it was not recognized. The library pacer_lib is a good start but not ready for use.